# How can I animate a set of points with matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, conways-game-of-life

I have an implemented Conway's Game of Life as:

```
def neighbors(point):
    x, y = point
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(-1, 2), repeat=2):
        if any((i, j)):
            yield (x + i, y + j)

def advance(board):
    newstate = set()
    recalc = board | set(itertools.chain(*map(neighbors, board)))

    for point in recalc:
        count = sum((neigh in board)
                for neigh in neighbors(point))
        if count == 3 or (count == 2 and point in board):
            newstate.add(point)

    return newstate
```

I want to visualize the result, so I tried to modify the given example from [Matplotlib animation example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/animation/simple_anim.html):

```
glider = set([(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x, y = zip(*glider)
mat, = ax.plot(x, y, 'o')

def animate(i):
    glider = advance(glider)
    x, y = zip(*glider)
    mat.set_data(x, y)
    return mat,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

but that just plots [the initial points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGEO.png).

Comment: You might be interested in other matplotlib implementations of the game of life, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653550/stopping-animation-conways-game-of-life) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196346/why-does-my-game-of-life-simulation-slow-down-to-a-crawl-within-seconds-matplot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have should actually produce an error. The problem is that you reference `glider` before you assign it.

Mind the local scope of variables in python functions. E.g. try

```
a = 0
def f():
    a = a + 1
f()
```

which will give you the same error.

In your code of Conway's Game of Life, you can circumvent this by making `glider` available to the global scope, `global glider`. Also make sure your axes limits allow for the animation to be seen.

Complete example:

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def neighbors(point):
    x, y = point
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(-1, 2), repeat=2):
        if any((i, j)):
            yield (x + i, y + j)

def advance(board):
    newstate = set()
    recalc = board | set(itertools.chain(*map(neighbors, board)))

    for point in recalc:
        count = sum((neigh in board)
                for neigh in neighbors(point))
        if count == 3 or (count == 2 and point in board):
            newstate.add(point)

    return newstate

glider = set([(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x, y = zip(*glider)
mat, = ax.plot(x, y, 'o')

def animate(i):
    global glider
    glider = advance(glider)
    x, y = zip(*glider)
    mat.set_data(x, y)
    return mat,

ax.axis([-15,5,-15,5])
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity @ImportanceOfBeingness, how did you generate this gif?

Comment: @ReblochonMasqueYou can [save any animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save) in this case: `ani.save("output.gif" writer="imagemagick")`.